# centering a video and a input box using flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a bit of a problem horizontally centering my video, input box and button in the center of the page. I've seen a few answers that say that I don't need flexbox and I've actually attempted to set my margin to auto(to center the content in the middle of the viewport)  to no avail. When I tried to inspect the code using chrome developer tools, It showed that my video, content, and form divs are taking up 100% of the width of the viewport, so it seems like that's the reason why I can't center it. Of course, I could be wrong. I'm stumped. Any help you guys give will be insanely useful right now. If this isn't clear let me know. This is what I have so far.
Thanks,
Anna

```
<div class="content">
<div class="video">
<h2>Want to read as fast as me? Follow the instructions below... 
</h2>
<iframe width="560" height="315" 
 src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/7SbJLfqPJgI" frameborder="0" 
 allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; 
 picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
 </div>
 <form>
<input type "text" placeholder="Tell us more about what books you 
like.">
<form>
</div>
<button type="submit" name="button">submit</button>
<footer>Anna Gibson @ 2018</footer>
```

Comment: Setting the margin will align the items to the center but it is aligning the items that have 100% width, it won't affect the content of those elements.  You could easily solve it by setting the the `body` tag to `text-align: center` or define the width of the actual elements and use margin auto.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so this is what I did. I made it so that the 'content div' encompasses the video, input box, button and footer, and text-aligned them all to 'center'
.
Here's an example of my code below:

HTML:

```
  <div class="content">
    <div class="video">
      <h2>Want to read as fast as me? Follow the instructions below...</h2>
      <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/7SbJLfqPJgI" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
      <form>
    <input type "text" placeholder="Tell us more about what books you like.">
    <form>
     <button type="submit" name="button">submit</button>

     <footer>Anna Gibson @ 2018</footer>
      </div>
```

CSS:

```
.content {
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

form {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


input{
  margin: auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

button {
  margin-top: 40px;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #7a420a;
  color: white;
  margin: auto;
}
```